# How to count items in a user input list in python

Tags: python

With the way my code is currently set up after I print num_of_items, it says zero I want it to count the items within the list created from the user input. How would I be able to get the number of items within the list itself?

```
grocery_list = []

while True:
  try:
    item = (str(input("Enter an item for your grocery list. Press <ENTER> when done: ")))
    if len(item) == 0:
      break
  except EOFError:
    break
    
num_of_items = len(grocery_list)
grocery_list.append(item)
print (num_of_items)
```

Comment: `grocery_list.append(item)` should be inside your while loop

Comment: You do not have to use `str()` operation on `input()` as it will always return a string. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work. Try this.

1. Input always return string so no need to use `str` in input field
2. Since you are using loop and you are appending value outside loop, it won't work, in every loop you have to append to `grocery_list` list.

```
grocery_list = []

while True:
  try:
    item = input("Enter an item for your grocery list. Press <ENTER> when done: ")
    if len(item) == 0:
      break
    grocery_list.append(item)
  except EOFError:
    break
    
num_of_items = len(grocery_list)
print(num_of_items)
```

Comment: This answer would benefit from elaboration and certainty. It "should" work, or it does? What was wrong with the OP's code and how does this fix it? You have also repeated some mistakes in the OP's code like extraneous parentheses and needlessly converting a string to a string.

Comment: `grocery_list.append(item)` would logically go after the break condition. This way you wouldn't add an empty item to the list before exiting the loop and wouldn't have to do `- 1` when defining the length of the list.

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code a little. I've tested it, and this works.

```py
grocery_list = []

while True:
  try:
    item = input("Enter an item for your grocery list. Press <ENTER> when done: ")
    if len(item) == 0:
      break
    grocery_list.append(item)
  except EOFError:
    break
    
num_of_items = len(grocery_list)
print(num_of_items)
```

Comment: What does this fix, and how does it fix it? This answer would benefit from elaboration.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This all depend on what your input looks like.
This code will work both with single inputs separated by Enter Key, and with a list of items divided by commas

```
grocery_list = []

while True:
    try:
        item = (str(input("Enter an item for your grocery list. Press <ENTER> when done: ")))
        if len(item) == 0:
            break
        item = item.split(',')
        grocery_list += item
    except EOFError:
        break

grocery_list = grocery_list.append(len(grocery_list))
```

Comment: This answer does not actually directly answer the question as asked and repeats some mistakes from the OP's code that you have the opportunity to remove in an answer: extraneous parentheses and needless conversion of a string to a string.